# Why is my config item not populating from my getenv() entry in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, environment-variables

I am using phpdotenv with Codeigniter. Codeigniter's environment setup doesn't quite work for this project.

I'm trying to set this in my config.php file:

```
$config['site_id'] = getenv('APP_ID');
```

phpdotenv is being loaded via the pre_system hook and getenv('APP_ID') is available throughout the app. I've also checked in the core and this fires well before loading config items.

```
$hook['pre_system'] = function() {
 $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(APPPATH);
 $dotenv->load();
};
```

The value of `$this-config->item('site_id')` is always `NULL`

Any advice as to why this is happening would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try load your config first, $this->load->config('your_config');. See if its help

Comment: the thing is - config.php gets called before the pre-system hook

Comment: @sintakonte In Codeigniter.php it fires just before loading config, as far as I can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jhodgson4 stated, CodeIgniter loads the configured constants first during the bootstrap of the framework (`core/CodeIgniter.php`). You can require and intialize dotenv at the bottom of your `index.php` file, before CodeIgniter.php is loaded.  This should allow you to use getenv in any of your config files.

```php
// ...at the bottom of index.php
require APPPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php'; // composer installing into application/vendor

// Use FCPATH If your .env is in the same directory as index.php
// Use APPATH If your .env is in your application/ directory
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createMutable(APPATH);
$dotenv->load();

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 */
require_once BASEPATH . 'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you would basically just do this :

```
require APPPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
  $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(BASEPATH . '../');
  $dotenv->load();
```