# How can I use Environment Variables in the Codeigniter Config file?

Tags: php, codeigniter, environment-variables

How can I use Environment variables to set up the encryption key in the config file for codeigniter?

I have set up a dotenv library and environment variables work everywhere else apart from the config file. I'm getting an empyty string.

`$config['encryption_key'] = getenv("APP_key");`

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088509/why-is-my-config-item-not-populating-from-my-getenv-entry-in-codeigniter

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to help...

Answer (score 0):

After a very long time, I noticed that using `hooks` could help:
So in `application/config/hooks.php` we write something like so:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class' => '',
    'function' => 'set_appkey',
    'filename' => 'appkey.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

and create a new file: `appkey.php` in `application/hooks` with the function

```
function set_appkey()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->config->set_item('encryption_key', getenv("APP_KEY"));
}
```

and finally, in config.php, we leave the `encryption_key` variable blank

```
$config['encryption_key'] = '';
```